# How to get text from div

Tags: javascript, jquery

My HTML code:

```
<div id="divText">
 Choose your item 
  <select>
   <option selected>item1</option>
   <option>item2</option>
   <option>item3</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

I want to display text as "**Choose your item item1**" (Here I want to get only selected item text from dropdown along with content of div ).

```
$("#divText").text() is getting text like  Choose your item item1item2item3
```

Comment: `var text = 'Choose your item ' + $("#divText select").val()`

Comment: I have around 10 dropdows and some cases these may hide/show. In this case I think it is not good practice.

Comment: So ask a clear question. Wrap your text with another element and get it easily.

Answer (score 0):

For you can filter of node type of text then concat with select value

```js
var result = $("#divText").contents().filter(function() {

  return this.nodeType == 3;
})

console.log($(result).text().trim() + $("select").val() )
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divText">
  Choose your item
  <select>
    <option selected>item1</option>
    <option>item2</option>
    <option>item3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```